# Smooth progress bar while copying folders VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops, directory, progress-bar

I'm making a program that copy subfolders to another folder, and my progress bar is not working nice, like when I'm copying a single subfolder its percentage is only 20% and stops there, but if it's 2 subfolders it stops at 50% and it's loading progress is like a shortcut it's not smooth.

can you help me guys?

**UPDATE**

this is my code:

```
Dim foldersToCopy As New ArrayList()

Sub CopyFolders()

Dim foldsrc As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(src)

    For Each folders In foldsrc.GetDirectories
        If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(dest & "\" & folders.Name) Then
            foldersToCopy.Add(folders.Name)
        End If
    Next

    Dim src As String = Form2.TextBox1.Text
    Dim dest As String = Form2.TextBox2.Text

    Dim fcount = Directory.GetDirectories(src).Length
    Dim ftransfer As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To foldersToCopy.Count - 1
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(src & "\" & foldersToCopy(i), dest & "\" & foldersToCopy(i), True)
            ftransfer += 1
            Pbar1.value += ftransfer * 50 / fcount
            Pbar1.Update()
    Next
End Sub
```

and btw, can I use the `WebClient`'s `e.ProgressPercentage` or `DownloadProgressChanged` for this code for smooth progressbar? =)

Comment: This does not look right. Try updating the progress bar using this code instead: `Pbar1.value = (ftransfer * 100) / fcount`

Comment: And you should probably set `fcount` to this instead: `Dim fcount As Integer = foldersToCopy.Count`, since you want all subdirectories right? Not just the ones in the current folder?

Comment: still the same, nothing changed. =(

Answer (score 0):

The ProgressBar value goes from 0 to 100 (%) so you have to scale the number in your loop to work out what percentage you have completed:

```
For i = 0 To foldersToCopy.Count - 1
    'copy the folder here
    Dim percentage = CSng(100 / foldersToCopy.Count * (i + 1))
    Pbar1.value = percentage
Next
```

Comment: It's not working, when i try to copy 1 Folder, the percentage jumps and stops at 50%, but if 2 folders it suddenly jumps at 100%.

Comment: `My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory` does not report it's own progress, so you can only step each time a whole directory is copied. You could copy file by file, which would give you more steps and so smaller increments

Answer (score 0):

OK a few changes. I've moved your folderstocopy declaration into the sub.
Also added a line to set Pbar1.maximum to the number of folders to copy minus one so that the last cycle of the loop, the progress bar will be at the end and you wont have to mess around recalculating how to get values between 0 and 100. Also

```
Sub CopyFolders()

Dim foldersToCopy As New ArrayList()
Dim foldsrc As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(src)

    For Each folders In foldsrc.GetDirectories
        If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(dest & "\" & folders.Name) Then
            foldersToCopy.Add(folders.Name)
        End If
    Next

    Dim src As String = Form2.TextBox1.Text
    Dim dest As String = Form2.TextBox2.Text

    Dim fcount = Directory.GetDirectories(src).Length
    Dim ftransfer As Integer = 0
    Pbar1.Maximum=fcount
    For i = 0 To foldersToCopy.Count - 1
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(src & "\" & foldersToCopy(i), dest & "\" & foldersToCopy(i), True)
            Pbar1.value += 1
            Pbar1.Update()
    Next
End Sub
```

Let me Know

Comment: but i need the progress bar not that one. =(

Comment: The only way to get it to go smoothly really would be instead of copying directories would be to create a list of all the files and copy them instead. Set Pbar1.Maximum to the number of files that you are copying and for each file that is copied, add 1 to Pbar1.Value.

Comment: Incicdentally - The progress bar is quite often jerky if you're doing time-consuming operations like directory copies that lock the main UI. You could try forcing Pbar1.refresh on every cycle of the loop, but this will impact the performance of the loop somewhat.

Comment: im testing 1 and 2 folders to be copied.

Comment: i updated my code, what i did was putting all the folders to an arraylist, then copy it all out, is that right?

Comment: when the copy starts the application hangs for a while, then after the copy has finished, the progressbar suddenly fills up and fast.

Comment: Yup. The UI gets locked while each directory is being copied. While this command is happening, nothing else can happen. when the individual copy operation completed your code carries on, but for some reason, the progress bar takes time before it updates, and doesnt get chance to redraw itself before the next copy operation starts on the next cycle of the loop and do on. When the loop finally finishes, the UI is free to complete the Pbar update and suddenly you get a full progress bar.. The only way to update the progress bar in finer detail is to copy individual files rather than folders.

Comment: You might want to look into using backgroundworker to do the file copying and reporting progress back to the main thread and handling it with a ProgressChanged event

Comment: oh so that's how it is, i guess i can't achieve anything with `CopyDirectory`, i'll try the background worker, but `WebClient` first wew so sad, well thanks for all the infos sir David, i appreciate it all.

Comment: Not a problem. Happy to try and help.